# Why magento2 Layered Navigation Price slider starts with Zero?

Tags: magento2, price, layered-navigation, price-slider

We are running Magento2.2.7. When we go to PLP, the price slider navigation starts with Zero. Even when we click/select a range of 0-0 , still it shows some products.

Comment: If my answer is useful to you then accept an answer, so it will be useful to another user. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chirag,
Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it didn't fix our problem. We still have the issue and we are trying to find the root cause for this. Actually this occues intermittently

Comment: Okay, nop. once you found the solution please post here so it will be used for another user :)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons for facing this issue. please follow below app step it might resolve your problem.

- Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- Disable all third-party extension.
- There are some corrupted products (some product price 0).
- Some of the extension which extends or override catalog & pricing functionality.

I hope it helps!